# Event Handler returning null c#?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, delegates, event-handling, eventhandler

I am implementing a swipe cards view in Xamarin.Android. I am firing an event from **RatingCardAdapter** to reset the swipe cards view after all the cards have been swiped. For the first time, the event is not null and the swipe cards get reset but on the second try, the event handler returns null. As a result, I cannot set the value of **shouldResetSwipe**. How can i solve this problem?

**Adapter**

```
public class RatingCardAdapter : BaseCardAdapter
{
private Context context; 
public event EventHandler OnLastCardSwiped;    
public RatingCardAdapter(Context context, SwipeCardsView SwipeView)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.SwipeView = SwipeView;
    SwipeView.SetCardsSlideListener(this);
}
public void OnCardVanish(int p0, SwipeCardsView.SlideType p1)
{
if (p0 == (Count - 1)) // p0 becomes 4 when last card is swiped
{
if (OnLastCardSwiped != null) //becomes null when rating adapter called 2nd time 
    OnLastCardSwiped(this, new OnLastCardSwipeArgs 
      { 
        shouldResetSwipe = true });
      } 
}
public class OnLastCardSwipeArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool shouldResetSwipe { get; set; }
}
```

**Activity**

```
private SwipeCardsView swipeCardsView; 
RatingCardAdapter ratingCardAdapter;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)    
{            
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_rating_session);
    swipeCardsView = FindViewById<SwipeCardsView>             
                    (Resource.Id.swipeCardsRating);                                                
    swipeCardsView.RetainLastCard(false);                
    swipeCardsView.EnableSwipe(true);     
    setSwipeData();
 }    
void setSwipeData() {      
    ratingCardAdapter = new RatingCardAdapter(this, swipeCardsView); 
    swipeCardsView.SetAdapter(ratingCardAdapter); 
    ratingCardAdapter.OnLastCardSwiped += (sender, e) =>  
       {   
       if (e.shouldResetSwipe) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("restart set " + e.shouldResetSwipe); 
            restartSwipeCard();     
        }}; 
 } 
 void restartSwipeCard() 
    {           
    Console.WriteLine("restartswipe"); 
    ratingCardAdapter = new RatingCardAdapter(this,swipeCardsView);  
    swipeCardsView.SetAdapter(ratingCardAdapter);        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating a new instance of RatingCardAdapter in  `restartSwipeCard` method, you need to subscribe too it's event also, since its tied to RatingCardAdapter intance. So move your lambda method to intance method to prevent code duplication and do same subscription inside `restartSwipeCard` method:

```
void restartSwipeCard() 
{           
    Console.WriteLine("restartswipe"); 
    ratingCardAdapter = new RatingCardAdapter(this,swipeCardsView);  
    swipeCardsView.SetAdapter(ratingCardAdapter);

    // need this subscription here too
    ratingCardAdapter.OnLastCardSwiped += (sender, e) =>  
    {   
        if (e.shouldResetSwipe) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("restart set " + e.shouldResetSwipe); 
             restartSwipeCard();     
        }}; 
}
```

Or even better rename `setSwipeData` to `initSwipeData` and update code like this:

```
private SwipeCardsView swipeCardsView; 
RatingCardAdapter ratingCardAdapter;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)    
{            
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_rating_session);
    swipeCardsView = FindViewById<SwipeCardsView>             
                    (Resource.Id.swipeCardsRating);                                                
    swipeCardsView.RetainLastCard(false);                
    swipeCardsView.EnableSwipe(true);     
    initSwipeData();
 }    

private void initSwipeData() 
{      
    ratingCardAdapter = new RatingCardAdapter(this, swipeCardsView); 
    swipeCardsView.SetAdapter(ratingCardAdapter); 
    ratingCardAdapter.OnLastCardSwiped += (sender, e) =>  
       {   
       if (e.shouldResetSwipe) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("restart set " + e.shouldResetSwipe); 
            Console.WriteLine("restartswipe"); 
            initSwipeData();    
        }}; 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Yura, you are a life saviour.

Comment: Glad it helped you! Don't forget to mark answer as correct)